# php file fails to load certain images after uploading the project to a web server

Tags: php, ftp, hosting

I've stumbled on the following issue with project after uploading it to a web server (godaddy.com): For some unknown reason img.php fails to load some images of random formats(jpg/png). I assume everything is done the right way because everything was working fine on my local machine. I used WinSCP to upload files. During the (ftp) upload i did not get any errors.

I get no errors or warning from php nor browser's console (which is why I'm so confused).

Is it anything that I'm doing wrong(am unaware of) or should i contact godaddy.com?

img.php code:

```
<?php
#   FILE USED TO LOAD IMAGES.
if(isset($_GET['type'],$_GET['f'])){
    #   ATTEMPT TO LOCATE FILE
    $dir=array();
        $dir['path']='src/'.$_GET['type'].'/';
        $dir['files']=scandir($dir['path']);
    foreach($dir['files'] as$i=>$val){
        $fNameArr=explode('.',$val);
        if($fNameArr[0]==$_GET['f'] && pathinfo($dir['path'].$val,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)==$_GET['type']){
            #   FILE FOUND. SEND RIGHT HEADER.
            switch(pathinfo($dir['path'].$val,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)){
                case'png':
                    header('Content-type:image/png', true);
                    break;
                case('jpg' OR 'jpeg'):
                    header('Content-type:image/jpg', true);
                    break;
                case'gif':
                    header('Content-type:image/gif', true);
                    break;
            }
            require_once($dir['path'].$val);
        }
    }
    unset($dir);
}else{
    #   SELF EXPLANATORY ERROR
    die('ERROR: dependencies missing!');
}
?>
```

live version on the project:
www.ekodom.com/v3/ (WARNING: CSS IS NOT FINISHED YET. MIGHT NOT WORK PROPERLY IN SOME BROWSERS)

additional info: apparently same goes for some .css files loaded via css.php which works in similar way(loads .css header and includes .css file);

Comment: You may not be getting any errors from PHP on your web server because they are likely turned off by default.  You can re-enable for debugging by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the offending page.  Other than that, we would need more information about the images to help troubleshoot.  But my first suggestion would to enable error reporting for troubleshooting, turn it off after you are done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have error_reporting(E_ALL) turned on in one of the files i include in index.php. Thank you for your suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally incorrect:

```
  case('jpg' OR 'jpeg'):
```

The `case` values can NOT be an expression. This `or` statement is literally the equivalent of

```
  case true:
```

You should have

```
  case 'jpg':
  case 'jpeg':
```

instead.

```
switch($foo) {
    case 'bar':
       ...
    case 'baz':
```

is literally the equivalent of

```
 if ($foo == 'bar') {
      ....
 } else if ($foo == 'baz') {
       ....
 }
```

With your `or` version, it'd be

```
 if ($foo == ('A' or 'B')) {
```

which compiles down to

```
 if ($foo == true) {
```

and then to

```
 if ($foo)
```

Comment: could you please explain a little better, my English is not as good as i would like it to be. I remember putting some simple evaluations in case(): (not in this example of course). So if understood well, when it comes to evaluating a variable for certain conditions it is better to use if() statements with multiple outcomes?

Comment: no. switch/case is nice for replacing a long series of if/else/else/else spaghetti logic. But you're using `case` wrong.

Comment: I've just tried your solution and it still doesn't work. I forgot to mention in my previous comment that it was working fine on my localhost (XAMPP) and some of my .png files till fail to load. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong. Actually the servers with their own PHP settings have a different mode of outputting an image directly into the browser with an image type heading.
I have had the same problem with 2-3 different types of hosts, as the same code worked for a particular host, and it didn't with the others.

Primarily I had no clue why, but then I found out that it depends on the specific image functions and their settings being done behind the scenes by these hosts. It also involved the type of encoding they use, and the mode of output stream they use with their output buffers.

If you want to stick to this host, you should better contact their technical team. Otherwise if you can move to a host where it would work, for example, all my image related codes including resizing and editing worked fine with Hostinger.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the thread is dead already i will post this solution for later searches. Today i was editing the code again and tried a different approach. It is similar to my previous code, but instead of require_once()/require functions i used file_get_contents() function.

Here's the overall result/code for img.php:

```
<?php
#   FILE USED TO LOAD IMAGES.
if(isset($_GET['type'],$_GET['f'])){
    #   ATTEMPT TO LOCATE FILE
    $dir=array();
        $dir['path']='src/'.$_GET['type'].'/';
        $dir['files']=scandir($dir['path']);
    foreach($dir['files'] as$key=>$val){
        $fNameArr=explode('.',$val);
        if($fNameArr[0]==$_GET['f'] && $_GET['type']==pathinfo($dir['path'].$val,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)){
            #   FILE FOUND. SEND RIGHT HEADER AND INCLUDE FILE CONTENTS
            switch(pathinfo($dir['path'].$val,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)){
                case('png'):
                    header('Content-type:image/png', true);
                    break;
                case('jpg'):
                    header('Content-type:image/jpg', true);
                    break;
                case('gif'):
                    header('Content-type:image/gif', true);
                    break;
                default:
                    die('ERROR: invalid file type!');
                    break;
            }
            echo file_get_contents($dir['path'].$val);
        }
    }
}else{
    #   SELF EXPLANATORY ERROR
    die('ERROR: dependencies missing!');
}
?>
```